# How to get FontAwesome char code from pseudo element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

We can get pseudo element with :

```
elem   = document.getElementById('element');
result = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').getPropertyValue('content');
```

But the result returns ""

Is there a way that I get the value from the CSS file ? (something like "\a8xx")

---

Thanks for the answers guys, I found the solution for my problem :

```
icons = $('body *');

for (var i = 0; i < icons.length; i++)
{
    elem = icons[i];
    before_content = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':before').getPropertyValue('content').charCodeAt(1).toString(16);
    after_content  = window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':after' ).getPropertyValue('content').charCodeAt(1).toString(16);

    console.log(before_content, after_content);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As simply as

```
''.charCodeAt(0) // 57661
```

If you then want to convert it to hexadecimal apply the `toString(16)`:

```
''.charCodeAt(0).toString(16) // e13d
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt

Comment: It might be worth adding `// 57661` as a comment to the code (or even as a note); just for clarity and to save people (like me!) from running to their console to look; also your code makes a clear assumption that it's a single-character string.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but all result I get from multiple icons with charcodeAt and codePointAt is 34. I don't understand why.

Comment: @ĐiềnBáQuan codepoint `34` is a quote (`"`) character. Check the string you're running it against

Comment: @ĐiềnBáQuan: then ideally you'd show enough of your HTML and CSS that we could reproduce your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @zerkms, I will accept the answer as soon as possible. Sad that I only have 14 reputation so I cannot upvode your answer, sorry. :)